# Update a range of post dates with SQL query in phpMyadmin

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I am trying to update a number of post(around 7000) in a WordPress database post dates within certain range of dates using this SQL query:

```
UPDATE `wp_posts`
SET post_date="2015-07-22 20:31:30"
WHERE post_date BETWEEN '2015-07-31 00:00:00' AND '2015-12-14 00:00:00'
AND post_status="publish"
```

I need to find posts which has dates from 2015-07-31 00:00:00 to 2015-12-14 00:00:00 and update them with 2015-07-22 20:31:30 and make them published

My server running with SQL server 5.5.44

What I am doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: What errors are you getting?  Perhaps you want to update post_status instead of filter on it (move it to the set instead of the where)?  BTW -- probably best to replace the double quotes with single quotes even though mysql technically supports them...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your query you're selecting the posts with the `publish` status instead of update them to `publish`. Try this query instead:

```
UPDATE `wp_posts`
SET post_date="2015-07-22 20:31:30", post_status="publish"
WHERE post_date BETWEEN '2015-07-31 00:00:00' AND '2015-12-14 00:00:00'
AND post_type = "post"
```

I added a `post_type` condition as you probably don't want to change revisions or any other posts type.